# Access Update Query Updating Both Tables of the SET Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, updates

I have created an update query in MS Access.  In the query there are two tables.  One is the table I want to update (`000DeleteMeNames`), and the other is a linked table (it's actually a list) in Sharepoint (`Work Orders`).  Every time I run the query, it does what it is supposed to and updates `000DeleteMeNames` like it's supposed to, however it also modifies the joined records in the Sharepoint list `Work Orders`.  No actual changes are made to the Sharepoint records, however the modified date changes and an alert is sent to me that the Sharepoint records have changed.

```
UPDATE 000DeleteMeNames INNER JOIN [Work Orders] 
ON WO_Num = [Work Orders].[Work Order Number]) 
AND ([000DeleteMeNames].[Date-Forecast] = [Work Orders].[Work Order Date])
SET [000DeleteMeNames].DummyField = [Work Orders].[Manager];
```

Is there a way to change my SQL so that the Sharepoint list is not updated, and only the records in the `000DeleteMeNames` table that are native to Access are updated? Am I doing something wrong in the SQL above?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE 000DeleteMeNames  
SET [000DeleteMeNames].DummyField = [Work Orders].[Manager]
FROM 000DeleteMeNames INNER JOIN [Work Orders]
    ON WO_Num = [Work Orders].[Work Order Number]) 
    AND ([000DeleteMeNames].[Date-Forecast] = [Work Orders].[Work Order Date]);
```